# Firebase SAML SSO Changing Email Address Creates New Firebase User Object

Tags: javascript, firebase, authentication, single-sign-on, saml

I'm puzzled if this is intended behaviour or if my implementation is incorrect.

I have implemented SAML SSO for my Firebase application using the following logic: `firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);`

I am using JumpCloud for my Identity Platform.

The SSO flow works as intended. If there is a user account on the JumpCloud Identity Platform who hasn't signed into my application, a new Firebase User Object is created which I can view in Google Cloud's Identity Platform and see the UID generated.

My question is, if a user is to change their email for whatever reason on the JumpCloud side, inside the same user profile in the Identity Platform, should this create a whole new Firebase User Object with a new UID, or should Firebase realise this is the same user who logged in previously with a different email address and update the Firebase Object accordingly, keeping the same UID?

My problem is the latter occurs. If an email changes in the same User Account on JumpCloud, Firebase sees this as a whole new user on my application and they lose access to all their Firebase user data on their original email address.

I couldn't see much info in the Firebase docs for this, but perhaps there is and I missed it.

Is there a way to have Firebase *know* this is the same user and let them log in accordingly with their new email address?

Thanks!